# Redundant conformance constraint warning in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I just migrated a Swift 3.1 project from Xcode 8.3.3 to Swift 4 / Xcode 9 GM. I managed to resolve most compiler warnings, but this one sticks and I cannot find any info related to this. The code compiled without warning in Xcode 8.3.3. I am using snippets to illustrate the issue.

The warning exact warning is

```
FirebaseArrayDelegate.swift:22:26: 
    Redundant conformance constraint 'T': 'FirebaseModel'
```

and relates to the declaration of `func initialized` (third line).

```
public protocol FirebaseArrayDelegate: class {

    func update(with block: (()->Void)?)
    func initialized<T : FirebaseModel>(array: FirebaseArray<T>)
    func added<T : FirebaseModel>(child: T, at index: Int)
    func changed<T : FirebaseModel>(child: T, at index: Int)
    func removed<T : FirebaseModel>(child: T, at index: Int)
    func moved<T : FirebaseModel>(child: T, from oldIndex: Int, to newIndex: Int)
    func changedSortOrder()
    func cancelled(with error: Error)

}
```

FirebaseModel is defined as

```
public protocol FirebaseModel: AnyObject, Equatable {

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
    var key: String { get }
    var ref: DatabaseReference { get }

}
```

and FirebaseArray as

```
open class FirebaseArray<T : FirebaseModel>: NSObject, Collection
```

Any idea what could cause this warning or might this be a bug in Xcode 9 GM? Thanks!

Comment: `FirebaseArray` already requires `T : FirebaseModel`; you don't need to restate that constraint with `initialized`, just say `func initialized<T>(array: FirebaseArray<T>)`.

Comment: I tried this before, but it did not resolve the warning. After the proposed change from @Hamish the warning is still ´FirebaseDatabaseUI/FirebaseArrayDelegate.swift:35:26: Redundant conformance constraint 'T': 'FirebaseModel''´, but now the yellow underline is underneath the "a" from "array" instead of underneath the "F" from "FirebaseModel".

Comment: @Hamish: Also I wonder why the following function declarations do not generate the same warning. The declarations for added, changed, removed are not generating warnings.

Comment: The other function declarations don't use `FirebaseArray<T>` in their signatures, so the constraint `T : FirebaseModel` isn't already known. Regarding the warning not going away, try cleaning your build folder and rebuilding; Xcode 9 annoyingly sometimes persists diagnostics even after you've fixed them (it clears for me when I make the change in Xcode 9 GM).

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks! So with Xcode 9 it's fixing and then cleaning.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in Swift, hopefully it will be addressed soon.

See: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6265